# How to display an image through Jquery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a div containing an image name :

```
<div class="productPic blockField">
   myimage.jpg
</div>
```

I want to display the image so i created a var :

```
var picUrl = '<img src="css/uploadedImages/myimage.jpg" />';
```

When i do `$('body').append(picUrl)` it displays the image properly.

Now i'd want to make the image appear when i hover the image name in my board. So i thought about the jquery tooltip :

```
$('.productPic:last').tooltip({content: picUrl});
```

But it triggers nothing; what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use jquery `.mouseover()` to call a function on mouse over

```
$( "div.productPic" ).mouseover(function() {
    $( this ).append(picUrl);
});
```